# How to create relation between a custom object and Products Line Item ? (Same as Quotes & Quote Line Item)

Tags: community, custom-object, sobject

I was looking for a clean approach where I can apply multiple Products' to a Proposal(Estimate).  Would need to be able to add an unknown number of Products to the Proposal(Estimate), along with details for each "Product Line Item".  Original approach was to create a Proposal(Estimate) custom object, and have a lookup relationship to the Products object, which contains a listing of all Products. And no need for pricebook.

Custom Object ------ Standard Objects

Proposal(Estimate)  =  Products

Proposal Line Item  =  Products Line Item

Comment: Your best bet is to implement a CPQ product from the App Exchange rather than reinventing the wheel. Opportunities as you know don't support more than one price book at a time. Within the existing framework, I believe you essentially need to be able to create "bundles" on the fly that you can add to a custom price book.